# Arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-gcc Misaligned Objects on .bss section

Tags: linux, gcc, arm

I have compiled my application and it has misaligned the objects in the .bss section.
For comparative propose, I have built the same code inside the CppUTest framework, with the same toolchain, and it shows fills in the same spot where my app misalign.

App Map File (misligned):

```
.bss            0x000132a0       0x3c
 *(.dynbss)
 .dynbss        0x000132a0        0x4 /home/fanl/re8kkernel/tools/linux-devkit/bin/../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crti.o
                0x000132a0                stdout@@GLIBC_2.4
 *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
 .bss           0x000132a4        0x0 /home/fanl/re8kkernel/tools/linux-devkit/bin/../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crt1.o
 .bss           0x000132a4        0x0 /home/fanl/re8kkernel/tools/linux-devkit/bin/../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crti.o
 .bss           0x000132a4        0x1 /home/fanl/re8kkernel/tools/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/crtbegin.o

####(MISSALIGN)####
 .bss           0x000132a5        0x0 obj_tgt/main.o

 .bss           0x000132a5        0x0 ../../common/lib/libhal-tgt.a(hal_app.o)
 .bss           0x000132a5        0x0 ../../common/lib/libhal-tgt.a(helper.o)
 .bss           0x000132a5        0x0 ../../common/lib/libhal-tgt.a(requirer.o)
 .bss           0x000132a5        0x0 ../../common/lib/libchelper-tgt.a(log.o)
 .bss           0x000132a5        0x0 ../../common/lib/libchelper-tgt.a(number.o)
```

CppUTest framework compilation (No misalign)

```
.bss            0x00020230     0x3190
 *(.dynbss)
 .dynbss        0x00020230       0x9c /home/fanl/re8kkernel/tools/linux-devkit/bin/../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crti.o
                0x00020230                _ZTVSt9exception@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                0x00020248                _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE@@CXXABI_1.3
                0x00020278                _ZTVSt9bad_alloc@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                0x00020290                _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE@@CXXABI_1.3
                0x000202bc                stdout@@GLIBC_2.4
                0x000202c0                _ZTISt9bad_alloc@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
 .bss           0x000202cc        0x0 /home/fanl/re8kkernel/tools/linux-devkit/bin/../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crt1.o
 .bss           0x000202cc        0x0 /home/fanl/re8kkernel/tools/linux-devkit/bin/../arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/crti.o
 .bss           0x000202cc        0x1 /home/fanl/re8kkernel/tools/linux-devkit/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/crtbegin.o

####(FILL HERE! NO MISSALIGN! I NEED THIS FILL TOO)####
 *fill*         0x000202cd        0x3 00

 .bss           0x000202d0        0x4 obj_tgt_test/test/mocks/call_counter.o
 .bss           0x000202d4       0x28 obj_tgt_test/test/mocks/terminal_intercepter.o
                0x000202d4                intercepted_output
 .bss           0x000202fc        0x0 obj_tgt_test/test/test_main.o
```

Below, I show the flags used to compile on the CppUTest Framework:

```
OS Linux
Compile C and C++ source with CPPFLAGS:
  -I
  ../../common/CppUTest/include/
  -Isrc
  -g
  -I
  ../../common/include
  -D
  AUTO_GEN_BUILD_TAG='0-g1db06ad'
  -D
  AUTO_GEN_FIRWMARE_VERSION='0.00-re8k-app-2013-09-16'
  -D
  SYSTEM_UNIT_TEST
  -DCPPUTEST_COMPILATION
  -Iinclude/CppUTestExt/CppUTestGMock
  -Iinclude/CppUTestExt/CppUTestGTest
  -Wall
  -include
  ../../common/CppUTest/include/CppUTest/MemoryLeakDetectorMallocMacros.h

Compile C++ source with CXXFLAGS:
  -g
  -Wall
  -include
  ../../common/CppUTest/include/CppUTest/MemoryLeakDetectorNewMacros.h

Compile C source with CFLAGS:
  -Wextra
  -pedantic
  -Wstrict-prototypes
  -g

Link with LDFLAGS:
  -Wl,-Map=app-tgt-test.map
  -g

Link with LD_LIBRARIES:
  ../../common/lib/libhal-tgt-test.a
  ../../common/lib/libchelper-tgt-test.a
  -L
  ../../common/shared-lib/
  -lzmq
  -lrt
  -lpthread
  -lm
  -lrt
  -lpthread
  -lm
  -lstdc++

Create libraries with ARFLAGS:
  rv
```

Finally, this is the build steps that makes an misaligned executable:

```
arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-gcc -I. -Isrc -g -I ../../common/include -D AUTO_GEN_BUILD_TAG='"0-g1db06ad"' -D AUTO_GEN_FIRWMARE_VERSION='"0.00-re8k-app-2013-09-16"'  -Wall src/main.c -c -o obj_tgt/main.o

arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-gcc  obj_tgt/main.o ../../common/lib/libhal-tgt.a ../../common/lib/libchelper-tgt.a -L ../../common/shared-lib/ -lzmq -lrt -lpthread -lm   -o app-tgt -Wl,-Map=app-tgt.map
```

**Please, Any help is welcome. I need to remove this misalignment from my code.**

Comment: Someone else asked *Why do you care?*.  I think this is a valid question.  Each input section has alignment constraints.  The `.bss` in **crtbegin.o** is obviously a single byte.  The next *section* from **call_counter.o** must have a `.bss` alignment of 4bytes.  You can solve it with a linker script or by other more kludgy means; knowing **Why?** may provide a more targeted answer.

Comment: I've got no Idea Why. I've compared all the makefiles looking for any compiler flag that could be the cause of this problem. I've found nothing.

Comment: The fact that the `.bss` is not aligned should not be an issue.  What happens because of this?  Does the start-up code crash?  Do you have a memory over-write?  There is theoretically no issue with having `.bss` aligned to a single byte.  It is clear *why the bss isn't aligned to four bytes*; The input **crtbegin.o** has a `.bss` with an alignment of only one byte.  I run `readelf -S crtbegin.o | grep -E "(bss|Name|Section)"` to give a last column of **Al** or alignment of **1**.  You can do the same.  Why is this an issue for you?

Comment: @artlessnoise 1) Kernel is issuing lots of warning on this. 2) It runs slower.

Comment: Look what I've found: obj_tgt_test/test/mocks/call_counter.o is the responsible for that **fill** of 3 bytes. If I remove the CppuTest objects, I get main.o misaligned.

Comment: Try adding an unused variable to **main.o**.  `static __attribute__((unused)) int foo;`  This will add a four byte value to **main.o**'s `.bss` section and will make the linker align the remainder.  The **ARM** does not support un-aligned loads/stores.  `cat /proc/cpu/alignment` to verify if the values increase when running the non-aligned `bss`.  This is an issue, with the tool chain or the Linux version.  There are many solutions besides the kludge I gave above.